# Angular 2+ - how to pass variables to SASS :before / :after pseudo selectors

Tags: angular, variables, sass, css-selectors

In Angular 2+ I need to pass value stored in component variable to CSS top property used in one of :before styles. In this case I cannot use [ngStyle] directly because it doesn't allow to access CSS pseudo selectors. I've tried to use it to affect CSS variable like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="summaries-graph-box">
     <div class="summaries-graph">
          <div [ngStyle]="{'--odds-top-height': graphOddsTopHeight + 'px'}" 
               class="summary-graph-column summary-plan summary-odds">
                  <span class="summary-value">123</span>
          </div>                 
      </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
graphOddsTopHeight = 40;
```

and in CSS I'm using:

```
 .summary-odds {
    --odds-top-height: 20px;
 }

  .summary-odds:before {
      min-height: 30px;
      top: var(--odds-top-height);
  }
```

The CSS variable is working however the value is still 20px (which is originally set within CSS) not 40px (provided from component variable).

I've also tried to use attr like this:

HTML:

```
 <div [attr.odds-top-height]="graphOddsTopHeight + 'px'" 
      class="summary-graph-column summary-plan summary-odds">
          <span class="summary-value">123</span>
 </div>
```

and then in CSS:

```
summary-odds:before {
    top: attr(odds-top-height);
}
//or
summary-odds:before {
    top: attr(data-odds-top-height);
}
```

However in this case the browser simply ignores top property and crosses it out.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with my code or what else I can do to pass variable from component to CSS :before pseudo selector?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the binding directive, something like this:

```
<div class="summaries-graph-box">
     <div class="summaries-graph">
          <div [style.height.px]="getSummaryHeight(summary.Plan)" 
               class="summary-graph-column summary-plan summary-odds">
                  <span class="summary-value">123</span>
          </div>                 
      </div>
</div>
```

And your function on .ts:

```
getTheRightHeight();
```

Should return a number value, for example: 40. (not 40px, just 40)

**--UPDATE**

If you still want to access the variable or the css, You can do it with something like:

```
@ViewChild("myDiv") myDiv: ElementRef;
```

and then you can access the div properties via `this.myDiv.nativeElement` and access the style property of the variable 
`(<HTMLDivElement>this.myDiv.nativeElement).style.setProperty('--YouCSSVariable', YourNewValue)`
 like in Javascript

Comment: Hey. Thanks for clue,  but the question is not about getSummaryHeight(summary.Plan) function and the height attribute but how to pass variable to :before selector for which I cannot use ngStyle. The getSummaryHeight(summary.Plan) function has nothing to do with this case it's just a part of my code ;)

Edit:
I have changed property names to make things more clear in this example.

Comment: The answer that I gave you is how to set specific value of an element based on value that come from .ts file. getSummaryHeight() was just an example to a function that return a value based on some logic and bind it to a css style. you cant send values to scss since scss is a precompile and at the end its compile to a plain css. @Morgoth

Comment: @Morgoth, I updated with another approach , Good luck

Comment: Thank you, it looks promising. I will give it a try and let you know the outcome.